# ERROR in cocoapods installation

Tags: ios, cocoapods

My log:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb

creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR="
compiling generator.c
linking shared-object json/ext/generator.bundle
clang: error: unknown argument: '-multiply_definedsuppress' 
[-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
make: *** [generator.bundle] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.3/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
```

Can you please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the Xcode Command Line Tools?

`xcode-select --install`